# Categories of narrative focus

Tags: terminology

I recall that a few years back a friend was explaining how novels can fall into various categories depending on what the focus of the story is.

For example, one category he mentioned was where the focus of the story was the Quest.  There’s a goal to be achieved, an enemy to be defeated, and the story is about “Will they make it?”  A good example would be *Lord of the Rings*.

Another category was one where the point of the story is the development of the characters.  How do they think?  How does what happen to them change who they are?  The events of the story solely serve as stimuli for change.  Good examples are *Crime and Punishment* and *Ender’s Game*.

Is there a name for that second category?

Comment: For your two categories, *quest story* and maybe [Bildungsroman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bildungsroman) (also *coming-of-age story*). But there are lots and lots of categories and no agreed-on categorization.

Comment: Thanks!  Want to post that as the answer?

Comment: It might be better to split this up into two separate questions

Comment: What would be the two questions?

Comment: Christopher Booker argued that there are [seven basic plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Basic_Plots): fighting the monster, rags to riches, quest, voyage and return, comedy, tragedy, rebirth. Also note that the terms "focus" and "narration" could lead you into a different direction, as "focus" in narratology is often used when refering to issues of narrative perspective, most notably in Genette's [theory of focalisation](https://www.lhn.uni-hamburg.de/node/18.html).

Comment: @henryflower: that list seems to completely miss coming-of-age novels (i.e., *Bildungsromans*), which would be a subcategory of the-man-who-learned-better in [Robert Heinlein's categorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Writing_of_Speculative_Fiction).

Comment: If you are looking for (1) the name for the type of novel represented by *The Lord of the Rings* and (2) the name for the type of novel represented by *Crime and Punishment* and *Ender's Game*, that would be two separate questions. (Another question might be what the book was that your friend got these categories from.)

Comment: @bobble, I've reworded the question to focus on a single category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest widely used term is **Bildungsroman**. This terms is often translated as "coming-of-age novel" but sometimes also as "novel of growth" (Childs and Fowler) or "formation novel" (Cuddon), which sound less narrow. "Bildung" can mean education, learning or creation (in addition to other meanings that are not relevant here). However, the term "Erziehungsroman" (literally "education novel") is sometimes used for novels that focus on a character's formal education.

The *The Routledge Dictionary of Literary Terms* by Peter Childs and Roger Fowler (Routledge, 2006) defines Bildungsroman as

> fiction detailing personal development or educational maturation.

Cuddon defines Bildungsroman as follows:

> a novel which is the account of the youthful development of a hero or heroine (usually the former). It describes the process by which maturity is achieved through the various ups and downs of life.

Due to the traditional emphasis on "youthful development", the term will usually be seen as too narrow to describe novels that describe that focus on the development of their characters generally. German literary theory also knows the term [**Entwicklungsroman**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entwicklungsroman) (literally "development novel"), which is sometimes regarded as a superset of the Bildungsroman. The Dutch Algemeen letterkundig lexicon treats the corresponding concept [ontwikkelingsroman](https://dbnl.org/tekst/dela012alge01_01/dela012alge01_01_02559.php) as a superset of Bildungsroman, Erziehungsroman (which may translated as "upbringing novel" to avoid confusion with Bildungsroman) and [Künstlerroman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnstlerroman) (literally "artist novel"). Cuddon says "Bildungsroman" is more or less synonymous with "Erziehungsroman" and does not provide an entry for Entwicklungsroman. (Childs and Fowler don't discuss the Entwicklungsroman either.)

The term psychological novel does not fit perfectly because it does not automatically imply psychological *development*. According to Cuddon's definition, "psychological novel" is

> a vague term to describe that kind of fiction which is for the most part concerned with the spiritual, emotional and mental lives of the characters and with the analysis of character rather than with the plot and the action.

(Thrall and Hibbard's older handbook has a longer entry for "psychological novel" that similarly does not discuss psychological development either.)

Conclusion: the term **Entwicklungsroman** would be the best fit if that term had been more widely accepted in the English-speaking world.

**References**

- Childs, Peter; Fowler, Roger: *The Routledge Dictionary of Literary Terms*. Based on A Dictionary of Modern Critical Terms, edited by Roger Fowler. London, New York: Routledge, 2006.
- Cuddon, J. A.: *The Penguin Dictionary of Literary Terms and Literary Theory*. Third edition. Penguin 1992.
- Thrall, William Flint; Hibbard, Addison: *A Handbook to Literature. With an Outline of Literary History English and American*. Garden City, New York: Doubleday, Doran & Co., 1936.